# Problema al obtener informacion de seguimiento 17trackPython

Tags: python

Estoy creando un código para usarlo en mi bot de telegram, la idea es obtener los datos de un pedido por 17track

En el código hago la consulta pero no encuentro el error:

> 200 {"ret":-9,"msg":"InvalidParams","g":"","dat":[]}

El código fuente:

```
#Codigo para obtener informacion de envios ---> 17Track

# Importamos las librerias
import requests
import urllib
import httplib
import json

#RH352992401CN
#ALS00359081


host = "17track.net"
link = "http://www.17track.net/restapi/handlertrack.ashx"
parametros = urllib.urlencode({"guid":"","data":[{"num":"RH352992401CNT"}]})
headers    = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36",
"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Referer": "http://www.17track.net/es/track?nums=RH352992401CNT&fc=0",
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
"Cookie":"__cfduid=d068db605f07408be5e77b46a1b5a3c9b1489755836; __atuvc=5%7C11; __atuvs=58cbdebee36d7721004; v5_ShowedWelcome=1; _ga=GA1.2.102662854.1489755840; __gads=ID=59a7a3123039d55c:T=1489755840:S=ALNI_MaM_SfNKpkXhENkfjaxZbBDSQ5txQ; v5_TrackingGuid=04998d4cd8844d089ba29484654e257a; _gat=1"
}

conexion   = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
conexion.request("POST", link, parametros, headers)
respuesta  = conexion.getresponse()
#ver_source = respuesta.read()
print respuesta.status,respuesta.read()
```

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar el enlace a la documentación de la API? El mensaje es bastante claro: "parámetros inválidos", así podrías limitar tu búsqueda a los parámetros que debes incluir en tu solicitud.

Comment: 17Track tiene API pero es PAGADA, la idea es "emular" la busqueda por PC